# Cyclic homology can be recovered from topological cyclic homology?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $S$ a $R$-algebra of finite type.
By an equivalence of ring spectra
$$
\operatorname{HH}(S/R) \simeq \operatorname{THH}(S)\otimes_{\operatorname{THH}(R)} HR,
$$
Hochschild homology $\operatorname{HH}(S/R)$ can be recovered from topological Hochschild homology $\operatorname{THH}(S)$.

Does this story extend to cyclic homology and topological cyclic homology?

Comment: Maybe you have to be a bit more careful. Topological cyclic homology is, roughly speaking, more akin to *negative* cyclic homology (homotopy fixed points) than to cyclic homology (homotopy orbits).

Comment: Spelling: "Hochschild", not "Hochischild".  I have edited accordingly.